# Angular routing with a star doesn't seem to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

The [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) say:

> - path can contain named groups starting with a colon (:name). All
>     characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams
>     under the given name when the route matches.
> - path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
>     star (`:name*`). All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under
>     the given name when the route matches.

I want to pass in a url parameter that contains a slash. Not to try and my own routing, but because the parameter values may contain slashes. The first method, `:name` stops at slashes. But the second, `:name*`, according to the documentation, appears not to.

I am using the following URL for test:

```
#/things/abc
```

This route works as expected.

```
$routeProvider.when('/things/:name', { ... })
```

But if I use this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/things/:name*', { ... })
```

It doesn't work at all. I'm using the latest stable version of Angular (1.0.8).

Have I misread the docs? Am I using it incorrectly? Is this a bug?

(I've not even got as far as passing arguments with slashes in them)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I assumed that released documentation would correspond to released software. Looks like it only applies to the unstable release.

Comment: The documentation has a release version ( that it corresponds to ) at the top left. You can change the dropdown to go to the relevant one.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't see that.